# Java: Is copying a ByteBuffer to a byte[] array a performance no-no?

Tags: java, sockets, memory, bytebuffer

Basically, my situation is this:

1. Server streams data from the client connection to a `ByteBuffer` object called **inQueue**.  This contains whatever the most recent stream of data is
2. Server must process the data in each of these streams and expect a packet of data in a specific format
3. The payload of data is to be read into a `byte[]` object then processed separately

Now my question boils down to this:  ***is copying the remaining buffer data (the payload) to a `byte[]` array bad for performance?***

Here's what it would look like:

```
// pretend we're reading the packet ID and length
// int len = LENGTH OF PACKET PAYLOAD

/* 
 * Mark the starting position of the packet's payload.
 */
int pos = inQueue.position();

byte[] payload = new byte[len];
inQueue.get(payload);

// Process the packet's payload here

/*
 * Set the inQueue buffer to the length added to the previous position
 * so as to move onto the next packet to process.
 */
inQueue.position(pos + len);
```

As you can see, I'm essentially doing this:

1. Mark the position of the complete buffer as it were just before the payload
2. Copy the contents of inQueue as far as the payload goes to a separate `byte[]` object
3. Set the complete buffer's position to after the payload we just read so we can read more packets

My concern is that, in doing this, I'm wasting memory by copying the buffer.  Keep in mind *the packets used will never exceed 500 bytes and are often under 100 bytes*.

Is my concern valid, or am I being performance-paranoid? :p

Comment: A better question to ask is " *"Does my method meet the performance requirements dictated by the customer?"*  To find that out, you need to run some performance tests.

Comment: I absolutely agree, and I'm doing that right now.  I was mostly just curious if people often do this, and if it's a known performance issue.  But thanks!

Comment: Odds are the I/O to read the packet and the processing done on it will completely dominate moving 100 bytes in-memory.

Comment: I should also mention, I am scaling this to handle up to 2000 users at once, which would be streaming these 100- byte packets every 600ms, oftentimes for hours on end.

Comment: `ByteBuffer#get()` already advances the *position* of the buffer, so I don't see why you're retrieving the initial position and later calling `Buffer#position(int)` yourself above. That call will have no effect.

Comment: @seh  Thanks for that pointer, I actually never thought about that.  I'll remove the marker.

Comment: The way I see it, if your buffer is a mapped native buffer, then you destroy its benefits by copying it onto the heap. Otherwise the difference will not be significant (you are making a second copy, so you already paid for the first one.)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Same applies if it is a direct byte buffer.

Comment: @EJP Maybe my terminology is just weak -- isn't "direct byte buffer" a more accurate name for my "mapped native buffer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is this unnecessary but, to answer your question, no you won't notice a performance change even when scaling up.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I got that from the comments, too ^.  Good to know I don't have to seriously revise my plan.

Comment: Please state how copying more data can possibly have zero effect on performance.

Comment: I never said that please re-read my answer. I said it will have no noticeable effect. The data is so small it that the margin for difference in performance is infinitesimal. He knows that it is different he wanted to know if the effects were detrimental to the program and the answer is no. However, I did state that is was unnecessary and that he shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid it. That's the whole reason for the ByteBuffer design: to avoid data copies.

What exactly do you mean by 'process payload here'?

With a little rearrangement of whatever happens in there, you should be able to do that directly in the ByteBuffer, calling `flip()` first, one or more `get()`s to get the data you require, and `compact()` afterwards (`clear()` if you're sure it's empty), without an intermediate copy step into yet another byte[] array.